# Keras says dimensions aren't equal, but I'm sure they are. Works when I set batch size to 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm trying to get a convolutional variational autoencoder to work on MNIST. It was working fine with I didn't use convolution layers, and had everything with Dense layers, but as soon as I added convolution, it fell apart. I'm sure this is something to do with how I'm dealing with Samples x 784 data, vs Samples x 28 x 28 data, but I can't figure it out. However, if I set the batch size to 1, it works.

I'm sure the final error code is telling me exactly what I'm doing wrong, but I can't understand it:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 28 and 1000 for '{{node vae/tf_op_layer_AddV2_4/AddV2_4}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT, _cloned=true](vae/tf_op_layer_Mul_2/Mul_2, vae/tf_op_layer_Mul_3/Mul_3)' with input shapes: [1000,28,28], [1000].
```

So here is the code

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

latent_dim = 2

inputs =tf.keras.Input(shape = (28,28,1))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = 1, padding = "same")(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = 1, padding = "same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = 1, padding = "same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = 1, padding = "same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

h = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
z_mean = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim)(h)
z_log_sigma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim)(h)

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
    epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(tf.keras.backend.shape(z_mean)[0], 2),
                                              mean=0., stddev=0.1)
    return z_mean + tf.keras.backend.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon

z = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_sigma])



#Size is now (3,3,8)                                     

encoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs,
                         outputs = [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z],
                         name = "encoder")
encoder.summary()


latent_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name = 'z_sampling')
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation = 'relu')(latent_inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((3,4,1))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters = 64, kernel_size= (3,3), strides = 2, padding = "same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding = ((1,0), (0,0)))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters = 64, kernel_size= (3,3), strides = 1, padding = "same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters = 64, kernel_size= (3,3), strides = 1, padding = "same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = 2, padding = "same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), strides = 2, padding = "same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = "same")(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D((0,2))(x)

decoder = tf.keras.Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')

decoder.summary()

#Build autoencoder network that combines both networks

outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs))
vae = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae')

vae.summary()

reconstruction_loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(inputs, outputs)
reconstruction_loss *= 28*28
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_sigma - tf.keras.backend.square(z_mean) - tf.keras.backend.exp(z_log_sigma)
kl_loss = tf.keras.backend.sum(kl_loss, axis = -1)
kl_loss *= -0.5
vae_loss = tf.keras.backend.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
vae.add_loss(vae_loss)

vae.compile(optimizer='adam')

vae.fit(x_train, x_train,
                        epochs=100,
                        batch_size = 1000,
                        shuffle=True,
                        validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

The models all seem right

```
Model: "encoder"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 28, 28, 1)]  0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 28, 28, 64)   640         input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)         (None, 28, 28, 64)   0           conv2d[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 14, 14, 64)   0           leaky_re_lu[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 64)   36928       max_pooling2d[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 14, 14, 64)   0           conv2d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 7, 7, 64)     0           leaky_re_lu_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 7, 7, 64)     36928       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 7, 7, 64)     0           conv2d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 3, 3, 64)     0           leaky_re_lu_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 3, 3, 64)     36928       max_pooling2d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 3, 3, 64)     0           conv2d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 64)     0           leaky_re_lu_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 64)           0           max_pooling2d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 2)            130         flatten[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 2)            130         flatten[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 (None, 2)            0           dense[0][0]
                                                                 dense_1[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 111,684
Trainable params: 111,684
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Model: "decoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
z_sampling (InputLayer)      [(None, 2)]               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 12)                36
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 3, 4, 1)           0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 6, 8, 64)          640
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2 (None, 7, 8, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 7, 8, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 7, 8, 64)          36928
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_5 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 7, 8, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 7, 8, 64)          36928
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_6 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 7, 8, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, 14, 16, 64)        36928
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_7 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 14, 16, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTr (None, 28, 32, 64)        36928
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_8 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 28, 32, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 32, 1)         577
_________________________________________________________________
cropping2d (Cropping2D)      (None, 28, 28, 1)         0
=================================================================
Total params: 148,965
Trainable params: 148,965
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "vae"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 28, 28, 1)]  0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder (Functional)            [(None, 2), (None, 2 111684      input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder (Functional)            (None, 28, 28, 1)    148965      encoder[0][0]
                                                                 encoder[0][1]
                                                                 encoder[0][2]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 260,649
Trainable params: 260,649
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

and here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vae2.py", line 108, in <module>
    vae.fit(x_train, x_train,
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 696, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3065, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:985 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py:385 call
        return self._run_internal_graph(
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py:508 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:985 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:3099 call
        return self._make_op(inputs)
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:3121 _make_op
        c_op = ops._create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs=[])
    C:\Users\wmkc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1815 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 28 and 1000 for '{{node vae/tf_op_layer_AddV2_4/AddV2_4}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT, _cloned=true](vae/tf_op_layer_Mul_2/Mul_2, vae/tf_op_layer_Mul_3/Mul_3)' with input shapes: [1000,28,28], [1000].
```

Comment: What is the shape of `reconstruction_loss`? I suspect the error comes from adding it and the KL loss with incompatible shapes. If this is the case, you can fix it by reducing both losses to scalars (e.g. average) _before_ adding them, or by adding two axes of size 1 to the KL loss to make the shapes compatible for broadcasting.

Comment: have you overlooked this `vae.fit(x_train, x_train,`? shouldn't it be x_train and y_train ?

Comment: @xdurch0 Thank you so much, changing to `reconstruction_loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf.keras.backend.flatten(inputs), tf.keras.backend.flatten(outputs))` fixed it. 

@sai It's an autoencoder, so that is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of `x_train` is `(60000, 28, 28)`, while the model requires an input shape of `(60000, 28, 28, 1)`. You can reshape the tensor and feed it to the network.

Comment: Adding `x_train = x_train.reshape((60000,28,28,1))` doesn't seem to help.